# What is hostdir type for storage pool in OpenEBS?

Tags: kubernetes, openebs

I've found the documentation hard to find, such as "type: hostdir" for storage pools. What is hostdir? Is this the only type of pool OpenEBS supports?

Answer (score 1):

Their documentation is missing explaining what `hostdir` is in their `StoragePool` resource definition. Judging by [this](https://github.com/openebs/openebs/blob/master/k8s/openebs-config.yaml) it's just a directory on your Kuberbetes nodes.

Also, they mention that there are 2 options: a directory on the host-os or a directory on a mounted disk. Either one of those 2 choices means that your directory will be on the node so it will be a `hostdir`, so I assume that's the only option available.

Hope it helps!